# Entity Framework query SPA

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am new to both SPA and Entity Framework and I have a question about the right/preferred way to do this.

I've got a web page to search customers by some filters (like name, surname, birthday date, phone number).

With ajax I pass from View to Controller a ViewModel object like this:

```
public class CustomerSearch
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Birthday{ get; set; }
    public string Phone{ get; set; }
}
```

Into controller I've got this search method:

```
 public List<CustomerList> GetCustomersList(CustomerSearch cs)
    { ..... }
```

In my application there are also DataAccess objects.

Now, the question is: how I can to do the query to database in smart mode?

I've thinked some scenario but i don't know which is the best about the layer separation.

1. I can ask to model an IQueryable object and perform the Where condition into controller
2. I can create a DataAccess method with the filters like parameters
3. I can create a Customer object (model object) filled with the filters value and pass this to model that perform the query

Which is the best method?

Thanks in advance.

Daniele

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the first option you present for the following reasons:

- Your second option would possibly require a lot of parameters if the number of possible search queries grows. It is generally not recommended to have a very large number of parameters since it leads to readability issues. (e.g. calling a method with 30 parameters)
- Your third option would make it impossible to create a query like 'BirthDate in 1998' or 'Surname starts with Q'.

By creating a class specifically for the purposes of querying you can do something like the following:

```
public class CustomerQuery
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BirthDay { get; set; }

    internal IQueryable<Customer> Apply(IQueryable<Customer> query)
    {
        var result = query;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name))
        {
            result = result.Where(c => c.Name == Name);
        }

        if (BirthDay.HasValue)
        {
            result = result.Where(c => c.BirthDay == BirthDay.Value);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Pay specific attention to the `internal` visibility of the `Apply` method. If you define this class in your Data Access Layer and this is defined in a separate C# project, the `Apply` method will only be visible to this Data Access Layer and not to the GUI project.

Calling it would be:

```
public List<Customer> GetCustomersList(CustomerQuery customerQuery)
{
    using (var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var customers = context.Customers;
        return customerQuery.Apply(customers).ToList();
    }
}
```

This can be further extended to support e.g. different types of string search (Contains, StartsWith etc):

```
public enum TextFilterType
{
    StartsWith,
    EndsWith,
    Contains,
    ExactMatch
}

public class StringQuery
{
    private readonly string _value;
    private readonly TextFilterType _filterType;

    public StringQuery(string value, TextFilterType filterType)
    {
        _value = value;
        _filterType = filterType;
    } 

    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
    }

    public TextFilterType FilterType
    {
        get { return _filterType; }
    }
}
```

If we would apply this to the `CustomerQuery` type:

```
public class CustomerQuery
{
    public StringQuery Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you look at the `FilterType` property of the `StringQuery` to find out if you need to do `Contains`, `StartsWith` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You have confirmed my original idea ;)